# Make sure that Nodejs Worker ready to work

Tags: node.js, node-worker-threads

How to make sure that the nodejs Worker is ready to work?

index.js

```js
const path = require('node:path')
const {Worker, BroadcastChannel} = require('node:worker_threads')

const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('channel-worker')
const worker = new Worker(
    path.join(__dirname, 'worker.js'),
    {execArgv: ['--no-experimental-fetch']}
)

worker.on('online', () => {
    console.log('online');
    broadcast.postMessage('test')
})

setTimeout(() => {
    broadcast.postMessage('test2')
}, 3000)
```

worker.js

```js
const {BroadcastChannel} = require('node:worker_threads')
const broadcast = new BroadcastChannel('channel-worker')

console.log('start worker');

broadcast.onmessage = msg => {
   console.log(msg.data);
}
```

console output:

```
online
start worker
test2
```

Expected when fired event `online` in worker.js BroadcastChannel is running already

Comment: what if your worker.js was wrapped inside an async function, waits on something then says `broadcast.onmessage=yourFunction`? the *online* event would fire, but it won't receive any message yet right? Idk if there's another way besides "ringing" the worker down before it "picks up" meaning setting up stuff for that on both ends ;-;